# Css width propertie override

Tags: css, css-selectors, overriding, width

I have  this css:

```
.chosen-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 13px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.extendedForm .chosen-container{
}
```

How can i made the second select with no width , overriding the generic selector on top. 
Thanks

Comment: width:auto!important

Comment: doesnt work, i need to remove it  as none !important dont exist

Comment: none doesn't exist and the default is auto :) ... maybe share you full code also

Comment: its done .chosen-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 13px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.editorForm .chosen-container{
    width: 100% !important;
}

Answer (score -1):

only use !important too:)

```
.extendedForm .chosen-container{
   width:auto!imporant;
}
```